# Tensorflow GPU cuDNn: How do I load cuDDN libraries?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, gpu

I am trying to use tensorflow with gpu and installed CUDA 8.0 toolkit and cuDNn v5.1 libraries as described in nvidia website. But when I try to import tensorflow as module in python3.5, it does not load cuDNn libraries (outputs nothing, just loads tensorflow module). And I do not observe speed in processing (same speed I obtained when I use CPU) with GPU.

Comment: Exact problem is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43059726/tensorflow-not-showing-successfully-opened-so-so-cuda-libraries-locally

Comment: You should give more detail, e.g. how do you _observe_ these things? What does your code, data look like?

Comment: I have no code just observed the problem by importing tensorflow. I installed with gpu support and installed CUDA/cuDNn but the interpreter is supposed to respond with message stating that CUDA libraries are succesfully opened but I cant see it. Also when I run a session, the speed of computation is same as the cpu computation speed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fresh install is the key but there are some important points:
1. Install CUDA 8.0 toolkit
2. Install cuDNn 5.1 version (not 6.0)
3. Install from source(bazel) and configure to use ensorflow with CUDA

Above steps worked for me! Hope it helps anyone.